# Populating a List<T> from a text file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate a list from a textfile.

```
public class Book
{
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

The text file has the title and year on one line after another.

```
List<Book> BookList = new List<Book>();

    //assume the path is correct
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

How do I populate the List from the array without overwriting the Book object every time through before both fields were populated for a given record.

```
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                int n;

                Book record = new Book();

                   if (!int.TryParse(line, out n))
                    {
                        record.Title = line;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        record.PublicationYear = line;
                        BookList.Add(record);
                    }
          }
```

Comment: Title:    Year: 1955
Title     Year: 1947

The titles are missing.

Comment: What's the format of the text file?

Comment: The text file has a title on one line and its publication year on the next.  So two lines per List record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you declare and instantiate the `Book record` within the loop, you're creating a brand new book each for line, instead of every other. Try moving it outside the loop:

```
Book record = new Book();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
       int n;
       if (!int.TryParse(line, out n))
       {
           record.Title = line;
       }
       else
       {
           record.PublicationYear = line;
           BookList.Add(record);
           record = new Book();
       }
 }
```